# Robocopy In Windows 10

Tags: robocopy

I am trying to copy files across our network in a batch file. I am going from the I: drive to the P: drive.

**robocopy I:\"Production Test"\"Six_Position_Flash_Programmer - Extra DIO"\Flash\Datalog\ P:\Staff\A_J\Data\1\CCA\168302-01 HrcProductionTestDataBackup.log**

The error message is: ERROR : Invalid Parameter #3 : "P:\Staff\A_J\Data\1\CCA\168302-01"

What is the error in my robocopy structure?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Robocopy executes two strings after the command. So, you have to put double quotes at the begining and at the end of the paths, and because of this, you have to escape the slashes too.

Try to run like this:

```
robocopy "I:\\Production Test\\Six_Position_Flash_Programmer - Extra DIO\\Flash\\Datalog" "P:\\Staff\\A_J\\Data\\1\\CCA\\168302-01 HrcProductionTestDataBackup.log"
```